# How to handle SignificantLocation change when an iOS app is in suspended state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

In my app I need to call an API service when there is significant change in the user's location. So I'm using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method and handling the API call in the corelocationdelegate method(locationManagerdidUpdateLocations). When app is in background or active state I can call API without any hesitation.

The problem comes when app is in suspended state. I know when SignificantLocationChange is triggered iOS wakeup the terminated app gives small amount of time to manually restart location services and process the location data and in this case we get call back to the delegate method,  do I need to use background task to call the API or API call should be made as before(as incase of active state). Currently the API call takes around 6-7 seconds. If it takes more than 10 seconds how do I handle the API call?

One more question, is there any problem if I don't call stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges? as my app always need to call the API when there is significantLocation change in user's location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "...I need to call an API service..." are you talking about making a network call to a server? If so, then yes, you should ask for background time.

I seem to remember you only have about 30 seconds of background time, and network calls can take unpredictable amounts of time.

You want to make the call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`, and then call `endBackgroundTask` once your server call is complete.

Comment: If you need your app to ALWAYS monitor significant location changes then not calling 'stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` should be ok. The significant location change API is designed to be power-efficient. (It only powers up the GPS occasionally, and uses WiFi hotspots, cell tower information, and other things to figure out your location without running the GPS all the time.